# Value provided in ExpressionAttributeNames unused in expressions: keys | DynamoDB Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to get the data from DynamoDB based on a few filters. (e.g.: get me a record where the productNumber and colorwayNumber is 'A', 'B'.) Following is the code snippet:

```
AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = DynamoDBClient.getInstance().getConnection();
Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> attrVal = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

Map<String,String> expressionAttributesNames = new HashMap<>();
expressionAttributesNames.put("#colorwayNumber","colorwayNumber");
expressionAttributesNames.put("#productNumber","productNumber");

Map<String,AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
expressionAttributeValues.put(":colorwayNumber",new AttributeValue().withS(colorwayID));
expressionAttributeValues.put(":productNumber",new AttributeValue().withS(productNumber));

QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
    .withTableName(ConverseConstants.PLM_PRODUCT_TABLE)
    .withKeyConditionExpression("#colorwayNumber = :colorwayNumber")
    .withKeyConditionExpression("#productNumber = :productNumber")
    .withExpressionAttributeNames(expressionAttributesNames)
    .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues);

QueryResult queryResult1 = amazonDynamoDB.query(queryRequest);


List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> results1 = queryResult1.getItems();
```

Following is the exception:

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: Value provided in ExpressionAttributeNames unused in expressions: keys: {#colorwayNumber} (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;

Hope I provided enough information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```java
.withKeyConditionExpression("#colorwayNumber = :colorwayNumber")
.withKeyConditionExpression("#productNumber = :productNumber")
```

Here you overwrite the first expression (`#colorwayNumber = :colorwayNumber`) with the second one (`#productNumber = :productNumber`). This way, `colorwayNumber` is actually unused in the expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below way and its working for me.

```
.withKeyConditionExpression("#colorwayNumber = :colorwayNumber and #productNumber = :productNumber")
```

or you can try below way which should work with FilterExpression and you can build it with DynamoDBScanExpression:

```
.withFilterExpression(("#colorwayNumber = :colorwayNumber and #productNumber = :productNumber")
```